# Bacula Backup Error

Tags: 14.04

```
Starting backup job BackupClient1 ..

Automatically selected Catalog: MyCatalog
Using Catalog "MyCatalog"
A job name must be specified.
The defined Job resources are:
     1: BackupClient1
     2: BackupCatalog
     3: RestoreFiles
     4: Daily_job
Select Job resource (1-4): 1
Run Backup job
JobName:  BackupClient1
Level:    Incremental
Client:   backupsvr-fd
FileSet:  Full Set
Pool:     File (From Job resource)
Storage:  File (From Job resource)
When:     2016-03-04 00:31:29
Priority: 10
OK to run? (yes/mod/no):
.. the backup job is now running. When complete, the results will be shown below ..
 yes
Job queued. JobId=8
You have messages.
messages
04-Mar 00:31 backupsvr-dir JobId 8: No prior Full backup Job record found.
04-Mar 00:31 backupsvr-dir JobId 8: No prior or suitable Full backup found in catalog. Doing FULL backup.
04-Mar 00:31 backupsvr-dir JobId 8: Start Backup JobId 8, Job=BackupClient1.2016-03-04_00.31.29_05
04-Mar 00:31 backupsvr-sd JobId 8: Error: dev.c:120 Unable to stat device /nonexistant/path/to/file/archive/dir: ERR=No such file or directory
04-Mar 00:31 backupsvr-sd JobId 8: Warning: 
     Device "FileStorage" requested by DIR could not be opened or does not exist.
04-Mar 00:31 backupsvr-sd JobId 8: Error: dev.c:120 Unable to stat device /nonexistant/path/to/file/archive/dir: ERR=No such file or directory
04-Mar 00:31 backupsvr-sd JobId 8: Warning: 
     Device "FileStorage" requested by DIR could not be opened or does not exist.
04-Mar 00:31 backupsvr-sd JobId 8: Error: dev.c:120 Unable to stat device /nonexistant/path/to/file/archive/dir: ERR=No such file or directory
04-Mar 00:31 backupsvr-sd JobId 8: Warning: 
     Device "FileStorage" requested by DIR could not be opened or does not exist.
04-Mar 00:31 backupsvr-sd JobId 8: Fatal error: Device reservation failed for JobId=8: Jmsg Job=BackupClient1.2016-03-04_00.31.29_05 type=5 level=1457069492 backupsvr-sd JobId 8: Warning: 
     Device "FileStorage" requested by DIR could not be opened or does not exist.

04-Mar 00:31 backupsvr-dir JobId 8: Fatal error: 
     Storage daemon didn't accept Device "FileStorage" because:
     3924 Device "FileStorage" not in SD Device resources.
04-Mar 00:31 backupsvr-dir JobId 8: Error: Bacula backupsvr-dir 5.2.6 (21Feb12):
  Build OS:               x86_64-pc-linux-gnu ubuntu 14.04
  JobId:                  8
  Job:                    BackupClient1.2016-03-04_00.31.29_05
  Backup Level:           Full (upgraded from Incremental)
  Client:                 "backupsvr-fd" 
  FileSet:                "Full Set" 2016-03-03 07:20:18
  Pool:                   "File" (From Job resource)
  Catalog:                "MyCatalog" (From Client resource)
  Storage:                "File" (From Job resource)
  Scheduled time:         04-Mar-2016 00:31:29
  Start time:             04-Mar-2016 00:31:32
  End time:               04-Mar-2016 00:31:32
  Elapsed time:           0 secs
  Priority:               10
  FD Files Written:       0
  SD Files Written:       0
  FD Bytes Written:       0 (0 B)
  SD Bytes Written:       0 (0 B)
  Rate:                   0.0 KB/s
  Software Compression:   None
  VSS:                    no
  Encryption:             no
  Accurate:               no
  Volume name(s):         
  Volume Session Id:      1
  Volume Session Time:    1457069476
  Last Volume Bytes:      0 (0 B)
  Non-fatal FD errors:    1
  SD Errors:              0
  FD termination status:  
  SD termination status:  
  Termination:            *** Backup Error ***
```

Answer (score 0):

See `/etc/bacula/bacula-fd.conf` and set an existing directory for the archive for the job you created for your backup.

You can use `sudo bacula-fd /etc/bacula/bacula-fd.conf` to check if you have a valid configuration.